# boostrap clearfix not working as expected

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, clearfix

I'm having some trouble with the code below when in the small viewport size (768-992px).  The other viewports work as expected.

At the small size I would expect two rows of four columns each; however, I am getting three rows of 4, 2, and 2 columns.

Removing the line `<div class="clearfix visible-lg-md-block"></div>` solves the problem at the small viewport size, but its removal creates causes an uneven display at the medium and large viewports.

Why am I getting three rows at the small size and what can I do so I only get two?

Thank you so much!

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
      Column 1<br>
      Resize the browser window to see the effect. Also try to remove the div clearfix line and see what happens.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Column 2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" style="background-color:lightcyan;">Column 3</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" style="background-color:lightgray;">Column 4</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" style="background-color:beige;">Column 5</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" style="background-color:lightyellow;">Column 6</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-lg-md-block"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" style="background-color:plum;">Column 7</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" style="background-color:thistle;">Column 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you expecting `.clearfix` to do? It will clear floated elements, and adding a visible class will make it only work on that specific screen width I think

Comment: I don't think `class="clearfix visible-lg-md-block"` is valid CSS, what I needed was `class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using `class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"` instead?

Your current code gets:

- -lg: 1,33 rows
- -md: 1,33 rows
- -sm: 2 rows
- -xs: 2,66 rows

Your structure is expected to produce 3 rows on -xs size!

You must change all `col-xs-4` to `col-xs-3` to get 2 rows

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Defining Bootstrap grid */

  The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:
  xs (for phones)
  sm (for tablets)
  md (for desktops)
  lg (for larger desktops)

  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> Demo </div>
  /* Above code will give you 2 columns for small devices */

  Refer : http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this: It helps,

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

.row class, Internally have the styles of clearfix class.

Hope it helps you, 
Thanks !!!