# Clearfix div doesnt clear the float in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In the second .row div, i have a .fizetesi_modok div. I want this .fizetesi_modok div to be under the other divs, so i want to clear the floats.

But the .clearfix does nothing here, the .fizetesi_modok is floated next to the prevous div.

In the 3rd .row, the .szallitasi_modok div isnt floated. Why is it working there?

```
<form method="post">
            <h2 class="megrendeles_title">Átvevő adatai</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box"> 
                    <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Vezetéknév </span>
                    <input required type="text" name="user_vnev" id="user_vnev" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box"> 
                    <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Keresztnév </span>
                    <input required type="text" name="user_knev" id="user_knev" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box"> 
                    <span class="megrendeles_input_title">E-mail cím </span>
                    <input required type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box"> 
                    <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Telefonszám </span>
                    <input required type="text" name="user_tel" id="user_tel" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
             </div>




             <hr>



             <h2 class="megrendeles_title">Számlázási adatok</h2>
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box"> 
                    <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Számlázási név </span>
                    <input required type="text" name="user_szamla_nev" id="user_szamla_nev" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box"> 
                    <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Irányítószám </span>
                    <input required type="text" name="user_szamla_irsz" id="user_szamla_irsz" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
                    <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Település </span>
                    <input required type="text" name="user_szamla_varos" id="user_szamla_varos" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
                    <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Utca, házszám </span>
                    <input required type="text" name="user_szamla_utca" id="user_szamla_utca" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
                    <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Adószám</span>
                    <input type="text" name="user_adoszam" id="user_adoszam" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6 szallitasi_modok">
                    <div class="szallitasi_mod_div"><label for="fizetesi_mod-1"><input type="radio" id="fizetesi_mod-1" name="fizetesi_mod" value="1" > Átutalás</label></div><div class="szallitasi_mod_div"><label for="fizetesi_mod-2"><input type="radio" id="fizetesi_mod-2" name="fizetesi_mod" value="2" > Előre utalás</label></div>                    </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
             </div>




             <hr>




             <h2 class="megrendeles_title">Szállítási adatok</h2>
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box"> 
                    <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Irányítószám </span>
                    <input required type="text" name="user_szallit_irsz" id="user_szallit_irsz" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
                    <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Település </span>
                    <input required type="text" name="user_szallit_varos" id="user_szallit_varos" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
                    <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Utca, házszám </span>
                    <input required type="text" name="user_szallit_utca" id="user_szallit_utca" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6 szallitasi_modok">
                    <div class="szallitasi_mod_div"><label for="atvetel-2"><input type="radio" id="atvetel-2" name="atvetel" value="2" > Gyári szállítás darus autóval</label></div><div class="szallitasi_mod_div"><label for="atvetel-1"><input type="radio" id="atvetel-1" name="atvetel" value="1" > Személyes átvétel az üllői üzletben</label></div>                    </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
             </div>                
        </form>
```

Comment: One of my suggestion is do not use Bootstrap, learn how to use grid or even flexbox it will be much easier for you handle any case you need and in my opinion is much simpler to learn it the bootstrap.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we could work on your problem?

Comment: Your problem looks like similar with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645986/boostrap-clearfix-not-working-as-expected Check it out

Comment: No float doesn't work in Bootstrap 4 because it uses flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

From your question:

- In the second .row div, i have a .fizetesi_modok div. I want this .fizetesi_modok div to be under the other divs, so i want to clear the floats.But the .clearfix does nothing here, the .fizetesi_modok is floated next to the prevous div.

  - this is because all **5** `input` elements (*"Számlázási név", "Irányítószám", "Település", "Utca, házszám" & "Adószám"*) before the radio buttons occupied 3 columns and your used `col-md-3` so it is placed next to the 5th `input type='text'` element
  - to resolve: you can use 'col-md-12' to ensure that the radio buttons are always on a separate row
- In the 3rd .row, the .szallitasi_modok div isnt floated. Why is it working there?

  - here you already the first 3 input fields (*"Irányítószám", "Település" & "Utca, házszám"*) had occupied **3** columns each, and your `szallitasi_modok` radio buttons had a `col-6` class on it and since there was place for only a `col-3`, it is bumped to the next row;
  - I added the class 'col-3' to it to show it comes back next to the first 3 input fields

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<form method="post">
  <h2 class="megrendeles_title">Átvevő adatai</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
      <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Vezetéknév </span>
      <input required type="text" name="user_vnev" id="user_vnev" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
      <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Keresztnév </span>
      <input required type="text" name="user_knev" id="user_knev" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
      <span class="megrendeles_input_title">E-mail cím </span>
      <input required type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
      <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Telefonszám </span>
      <input required type="text" name="user_tel" id="user_tel" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>




  <hr>



  <h2 class="megrendeles_title">Számlázási adatok</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
      <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Számlázási név </span>
      <input required type="text" name="user_szamla_nev" id="user_szamla_nev" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
      <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Irányítószám </span>
      <input required type="text" name="user_szamla_irsz" id="user_szamla_irsz" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
      <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Település </span>
      <input required type="text" name="user_szamla_varos" id="user_szamla_varos" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
      <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Utca, házszám </span>
      <input required type="text" name="user_szamla_utca" id="user_szamla_utca" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
      <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Adószám</span>
      <input type="text" name="user_adoszam" id="user_adoszam" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 szallitasi_modok">
      <div class="szallitasi_mod_div"><label for="fizetesi_mod-1"><input type="radio" id="fizetesi_mod-1"
              name="fizetesi_mod" value="1"> Átutalás</label></div>
      <div class="szallitasi_mod_div"><label for="fizetesi_mod-2"><input type="radio" id="fizetesi_mod-2"
              name="fizetesi_mod" value="2"> Előre utalás</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>




  <hr>




  <h2 class="megrendeles_title">Szállítási adatok</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
      <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Irányítószám </span>
      <input required type="text" name="user_szallit_irsz" id="user_szallit_irsz" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
      <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Település </span>
      <input required type="text" name="user_szallit_varos" id="user_szallit_varos" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 megrendeles_box">
      <span class="megrendeles_input_title">Utca, házszám </span>
      <input required type="text" name="user_szallit_utca" id="user_szallit_utca" class="form-control input-lg" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 szallitasi_modok">
      <div class="szallitasi_mod_div"><label for="atvetel-2"><input type="radio" id="atvetel-2" name="atvetel"
              value="2"> Gyári szállítás darus autóval</label></div>
      <div class="szallitasi_mod_div"><label for="atvetel-1"><input type="radio" id="atvetel-1" name="atvetel"
              value="1"> Személyes átvétel az üllői üzletben</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```